# Tile error Google Earth Engine ; Image 0 does not have a system: time_start property

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series

[![I am getting this error in my code,I want to analyse time series, Any suggestions how to deal with it?][1]][1][! [[][1]][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h5Vh.png)

[1]: here is the code link
https://code.earthengine.google.com/f81d964229bff9f264c18e17cb0a98ff

here is the asset file
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/atupelye/Rungwa_dissolved

Comment: Can you share your asset?

Comment: thanks, I have shared the asset

Answer (score 2):

Definetly one issue is that your system:time_start property is missing for the Landtrendr Algorithm. When you create a median annual composite it needs to be define, for example as the minimum value inside the annual collection:

```
// Map over the list of years to generate a composite for each year.
var yearCompList = yearList.map(function(year){
  var yearCol = col.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'));

   var yearComp = yearCol.reduce(myReducer);
  var imgList = yearCol.aggregate_array('constant');
  var systemStart = yearCol.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.min(), ['system:time_start']).get('min');
  // Reduce (composite) the images for this year.
  var nBands = yearComp.bandNames().size();
 return yearComp.set({
    'year': year,
    'image_list': imgList,
    'n_bands': nBands,
    'system:time_start': systemStart
  });
});
```

Can't be for sure though without the asset.

Comment: I have run it, but I am still getting another error, Tile error: Internal error has occured, I wonder if its linked to the previous error

Comment: Most likely a scaling error: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging